# ToneTag Payment SDK integration

Tags: android

Does anyone integrated TONETAG payment integration. Could you please help me where can I get the SDK and how can I integrate it?

I referred [this](https://www.tonetag.com/index.html) site  but I could not figure it out.

Comment: make sure they provided TONETAG SDK for integration or not ...

Comment: Yea they were providing with sdk for integration. After logging into their website they provided button like download SDK. But after downloading only sample pdf was found. Need help for getting SDK